# Angular and Firebase - How to only display items under one node

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat

Currently, I have a firebase structure that lists projects with items under each project. Currently, the code below displays all the projects. Now when I click on a project it links to the items page. However, how would i go about displaying all items that are related to that project only?

The fire base structure has:

```
data
   > project unique id's
       > items
            > item id's
                > item title
```

```js
app.controller("ItemDisplayController", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
 var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("data");
 $scope.data = $firebaseArray(ref);
});
```

```html
<li ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <a href="#/items">
      {{ project.projecttitle}}
    </a>
</li>
```

So essentially if project one has two items and project two has 10 items, when I click on project one, i'm directed to the items page and two item titles are displayed.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: create a `getProject(projectId)` method in you controller, this accepts the `projectId` and returns all items linked to that `projectId`

Comment: Hi Azola. Thank you for the rapid response. I'm relatively new to this. Would you mind explaining how to do that please? Appreciate your time.

Comment: the name of the method should be getItems infact; I need  to see your angular js controller code in order for me to assist

Comment: Thanks Azola. I've added it.

Comment: Have a look here; https://jsfiddle.net/10utt0fc/ It might not be what you are looking for exactly, but that's where you need to start

Comment: Thanks Azola. Unfortunately not. Currently when I click on a project and navigate to the views control, nothing happens, Not sure how the items data is carried forward to that view.

Comment: That is why I display on the same page just to get you started. For navigation you might wanna look at [angular ui router]:https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Again, thanks Azola. As mentioned in my original post. I have the angular route correctly set up and it navigates to the correct items view fine. My questions is how to carry data into that view based on the item I clicked on. Again, apologies if I'm iterating myself. I'm new to this. Appreciate the time.

Comment: Need to create an angular service that does what I did in the sample controller that I sent to you

Comment: Bugger. I thought it sounded like a straight forward process to get the child items. ah well. Thanks for your time anyway Azola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the structure of the data returned from `$firebaseArray` service:

```
app.controller("ItemDisplayController", function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("data");
    $scope.data = $firebaseArray(ref);
    $scope.data.$loaded().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);  
        throw error;
    );
});
```

The `$firebaseArray` service attaches a method called `$loaded` to the returned object that returns a [$q Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) promise that resolves fulfilled or rejected with the data from the server.

Use that to diagnose the problem.